# Select query to field retrieve information - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress table **wp_options**, With a field named as **option_value**

In option_value fields there are a lot of records like the following

```
a: 767: {
    i: 0;a: 8: {
        s: 7: "user_id";s: 1: "1";s: 10: "media_name";s: 17: "550504eb10347.jpg";s: 18: "media_display_name";s: 19: "about_play_img1.jpg";s: 10: "media_type";s: 5: "photo";s: 9: "media_url";s: 95: "example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 10: "media_path";s: 111: "/home/content/30/7469030/html/1hotdesign/theplayexperience/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 14: "thumbnail_path";s: 105: "example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/thumbnail/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 8: "media_id";i: 0;
    }i: 1;a: 8: {
        s: 7: "user_id";s: 1: "1";s: 10: "media_name";s: 17: "55052a098c146.jpg";s: 18: "media_display_name";s: 22: "Ashleymarie 199 Bw.jpg";s: 10: "media_type";s: 5: "photo";s: 9: "media_url";s: 95: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 10: "media_path";s: 111: "/home/content/30/7469030/html/1hotdesign/theplayexperience/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 14: "thumbnail_path";s: 105: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/thumbnail/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 8: "media_id";i: 1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a query where the user_id and its associated image are displayed.

```
Ex. user_id:1 - image 55052a098c146.jpg, imagename.jpg
Ex. user_id:2 - image 55052a098c146.jpg, imagename.jpg
```

and soon.

can this be done in one select Query.

I checked the following, but it was of no help.
https://wpbits.wordpress.com/2007/08/08/a-look-inside-the-wordpress-database/

Comment: You can get the values using unserialize()

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You shouldn't query Wordpress database directly, use WP functions instead, like [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class, depends of your need. Those functions handle all the taxonomy / meta queries for you.

Some good reading about that : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

The only case when you should use WPDB class to query the database directly is when you're working with custom tables.

So, in your case, assuming you want to get the profile picture, you can use the [`get_avatar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) function:

```
echo get_avatar(1) // will display the profile picture of user with ID 1
```